# making an invite manager with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot that has a command where it will tell you every bodies invites from greatest to least in the discord server. This is the code I have but I don't know why it isn't working.

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'invites',
 description: 'invite command',
 callback: (message) => {
  const { guild } = message;

  guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
   const inviteCounter = {};

   invites.forEach((Invite) => {
    const { uses, inviter } = Invite;
    const { username, discriminator } = inviter;

    const name = `${username}#${discriminator}`;

    inviteCounter[name] = (inviteCounter[name] || 0) + uses;
   });

   let replyText = 'invites:';

   for (const invite in inviteCounter) {
    const count = inviteCounter[invite];
    replyText += `\n${invite} has invited ${count} member(s)!`;
   }

   message.reply(replyText);
  });
 },
};
```

This is my command handler, i have 2 other commands that i know work and I've been changing the invite command some cause I cant get it to work.

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '+';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Baysides-utilities is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if(command === 'ticket'){
    
       client.commands.get('ticket').execute(message, args, client, fs);
    }

    if(command === 'invites'){

       client.commands.get('invites');
     }

    if(command === 'grow'){

        client.commands.get('grow').execute(message, args, client, fs);
     }


});

client.login('I have it in the code just not showing it here');
```

Comment: Could you show the error you're getting?

Comment: There isn't an error, just nothing is happening.

Comment: Could you show your command handler? Are you sure the command's actually being executed?

Comment: yea I'll send it, i'm pretty sure it works cause my 2 other commands work but i  might've done something wrong.

Comment: Try putting in `console.log()` checkpoints so you can see where the bot reaches and where it stops.

Comment: Oh, I think the problem is that you named your function `callback`, but in the command handler you were executing a function called `execute`, which in this command's case doesn't exist

Comment: okay, so should i change `callback` with `execute`, or the other way around?

Comment: Either way works, just make sure it's consistent with all or your commands.

Comment: Okay, thanks. If I change execute to callback in the command handler what would the code look like.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You said that I need to change execute to callback in the command handler, could you give me an example of what it would look like

Comment: Just replace `client.commands.get().execute()` to `client.commands.get().callback()`